# How to remove the special character that write_json is adding to the string in boost C++

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

write_json is converting the string `"test/123"` as `"test\/123"`. How to remove the special character (`\`) that write_json is adding to the string in boost C++

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: What is `write_json`? Not standard C++: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=write_json+site%3Acppreference.com You should add some reference.

Comment: @kebs It's tagged [tag:boost] (for [tag:boost-propertytree], apparently)

Comment: @sehe, ok, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being escaped. It's valid JSON, so any JSON parser should be able to read it correctly.

*Put bluntly, yours is not a problem. If you think it is, you're doing something wrong.*

Other than that, please don't use Boost Property Tree as if it were a JSON library. It is not.

Boost 1.75 introduced Boost Json, which **is**.

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Po49GWTK3)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace json = boost::json;

int main() {
    {
        json::value s = "test/123";
        std::cout << json::serialize(s) << std::endl;
    }

    {
        auto s = json::parse(R"("test\/123")");
        std::cout << json::serialize(s) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"test/123"
"test/123"
```